# Irreducible unitary representations of $ \Bbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{R} $.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

> Let $ \alpha $ be the action of $ \Bbb{R} $ on the group $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $ defined by $ \alpha_{t} \! \left( \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} \right) = \exp \! \left( \begin{bmatrix} t & 0 \\ 0 & - t \end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} $. Let $ G = \Bbb{R}^{2} \rtimes_{\alpha} \Bbb{R} $. Determine the equivalence classes of irreducible unitary representations of $ G $.

I came up with two approaches.

The first one is to actually work with the matrices.

The other one is to use Schur’s Lemma and use the fact that an irreducible representation $ \pi $ on the center of $ G $ is just a character.

But with those approaches, I don’t know how to go further and I guess it’s because I’m not really sure whether my approach is reasonable.

Thanks.

Comment: A few questions: What is $\Bbb{R}_n$? Did you mean $\Bbb{R}^n$ everywhere? $\alpha_t$ is a 2x2--matrix. Are we to infer that $n=2$ or what is the action? The version of Schur's lemma I'm familiar with does not imply that all irreducible representations are just characters. What does your version state? It seems more likely to me that solvability of the group might come into play. Admittedly I'm a bit rusty on the Lie group side (more familiar with Lie algrebra and algebraic groups).

Comment: Sorry for typos. I corrected them. If there's any confusion or typo, let me know. And I meant Schur's lemma on the center of $G$.

Comment: Your group is nilpotent, connected and simply connected. The general theory developed by Kirillov known as the *orbit method* describes the irreducible unitary representations in terms of coadjoint orbits. You should read about that.

Comment: Are you talking about finite dimensional reps?

Comment: Yes. finite dimensional reps. But the thing is that this problem was given in $C^*$-algebra class. So I'm not really familiar with the orbit method. And that's why I've been trying to exploit the Schur's lemma thought it was not successful.

Comment: The finite dimensional case is infinitely simpler... A representation of your group gives you a representation of its Lie algebra, and the latter is irreducible if the former is (because the exponential map of the group is surjective) So you can try to classify first the irreducible reps of the Lie algebra —this is not hard, since it is a nilpotent Lie algebra: Lie's theorem tells us that its (finite-dimensonal) irreps are all one dimensional.

Comment: You *should* be explicit about what reps you have in mind, really, and give a minimal decription of your background (for otherwise it is very hard to give useful answers!)

Comment: When I say a representation of $G$, I mean a homomorphism from $G$ to the space of bounded operators on a hilbert space. But in this problem, I think it should be seen as a homomorphism from $G$ to the general linear group. I know what nilpotent Lie algebra is, but I've never worked with it before. So I will look it up now

Comment: Ok, then you do **not** mean finite dimensional representations! (Unless you mean finite dimensional Hilbert spaces...) In that case, the orbit method is what you are after.